# Sketch of Spivaks proof of the Inverse Function Theorem for Multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Below is the proof of the inverse function theorem for multivariable functions given in Spivaks "Calculus on Manifolds".  I have made a few interpretations regarding his reasoning and want to know if I have interpreted correctly.

- He spends the majority of the first part of the proof proving that $f$ is bijective, as this implies the existence of an inverse.
- The only time we use that $Df(a)=I$ is when we define $\mu=Df(a)$ and write $\mu^{-1}\big(f(x_1)-f(x)\big)=\mu^{-1}\big(\mu(x_1-x)+\phi(x_1-x)\big)$ $=$ $\mu^{-1}\big(\mu(x_1-x)\big)+\mu^{-1}\big(\phi(x_1-x)\big)$, since $\mu=I$ implies that $\mu^{-1}=\mu=I$ ,which gives that $\mu^{-1}$ is linear.  Besides that I don't see any other application of the property $Df(a)=I$ we established in the opening lines of the proof.
- $detf'(a)\neq 0$ is only used in the proof to guarantee that there exists a neighborhood around $f'(a)$ such that every element is non-zero; and then this implication is used to show that we must have $y^{i}-f^i(x)=0$, $\forall i$

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: He should really have introduced notation for the boundary of a set ...

Answer (score 2):

No, the main thing you've overlooked is that he uses $Df(a)=I$ in a crucial way when he considers $g(x)=f(x)-x$ to prove 4. (Intuitively, if $Df(a)=I$, then near $a$ the function $f$ is close to the identity function.) And, no, $\det Df(a)\ne 0$ is used to know that $Df(a)$ is invertible. That's what makes the whole proof get started.

Comment: I do recall from Munkres' text that $Df(a)\neq 0$ was proven to be a necessary, and sufficient when $f$ is $c^r$, condition for the invertibility of $f$.  But am I correct when I say that he spends the first half proving that $f$ is bijective in order to prove that there is indeed an inverse?  just below 5. he says "for any $y$, there is a unique $x$". $f$ being invertible, and $f$ having an inverse mean different things, right?

Comment: First of all, these things are all local. But, no, saying a *function* is invertible is equivalent to saying it has an inverse function. ... Munkres and Spivak basically have the same proof. If you want to see a different one, you can check out some of my lectures on YouTube. The relevant ones are (in the second list) #17, 18, 21.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $Df = I$ is only a simplification, and nothing deep there. Only invertibility matters here.

A crucial part/corollary of IFT is that an open set is mapped to an open set, and not a singular formation at $f(x_0)$. This is somewhat under-emphasized in this proof.